# Creating offline installer for Visual Studio, includeRecommended/includeOptional switches doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2017, installation, offline, visual-studio-2019

Using [Create an offline installer for Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio), [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio) and [Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise) I tired to create `offline installer` for `Visual Studio 2017, Enterprise`, first time I used following:

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node` and its worked and I could install VS successfully.

After that I tired to update created files and add `Recommended/Optional` Components to some `workload`s, so I followed mentioned article, article says by adding `--includeRecommended` (*also `--includeOptional`*) switch, installer will download `Recommended` (*`Optional`*) components too. so I added (for ex.) `--includeRecommended` switch like this:

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout --lang en-US --includeRecommended --includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node`, and **doesn't work** (the second cmd (that shows download progress) closed immediately), in summary, I tired following commands too, and non of them doesn't work neither:

- `vs_enterprise.exe --layout --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --includeRecommended`
- `vs_enterprise.exe --layout --lang en-US --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools`
- ... (*I mean I changed order of all parameters, actually **I tired all possible options***)

Also I tired in new (empty) folder, but no success.

I googled, but I found nothing, only some example that already exists in http://learn.microsoft.com.

How should I use `includeRecommended/includeOptional` switches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (2021-11-10)**

Following solution works perfectly for `Visual Studio 2022`

**Update**

Here is the list of all available workloads (*linked to their details*) and usage sample:

- Workload `ID`
- [Visual Studio core editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?vs-2019&view=vs-2019#visual-studio-core-editor-included-with-visual-studio-enterprise-2019) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor`
- [Azure development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?vs-2019&view=vs-2019#azure-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure`
- [Data storage and processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?vs-2019&view=vs-2019#data-storage-and-processing) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data`
- [Data science and analytical applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#data-science-and-analytical-applications) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataScience`
- [.NET desktop development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#net-desktop-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop`
- [Game development with Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#game-development-with-unity) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame`
- [Linux development with C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#linux-development-with-c) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat`
- [Desktop development with C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#desktop-development-with-c) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop`
- [Game development with C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#game-development-with-c) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame`
- [Mobile development with C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#mobile-development-with-c) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile`
- [.NET Core cross-platform development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#net-core-cross-platform-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools`
- [Mobile development with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#mobile-development-with-net) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat`
- [ASP.NET and web development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#aspnet-and-web-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`
- [Node.js development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#nodejs-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node`
- [Office/SharePoint development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#officesharepoint-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office`
- [Python development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#python-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python`
- [Universal Windows Platform development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#universal-windows-platform-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal`
- [Visual Studio extension development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#visual-studio-extension-development) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtension`
- [Unaffiliated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2019#unaffiliated-components)

Create an offline installer: [Documentation for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) / [Documentation For VS2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

1. Download the Visual Studio bootstrapper (*e.g: `vs_enterprise.exe`*)
2. Create a local install cache

- e.g: `D:\whatever\vs_enterprise.exe --layout d:\whatever --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --lang en-US`

3. Double click on `vs_enterprise.exe` to install Visual Studio from the local cache

If you want to update prev. created local cache, run `vs_enterprise.exe --layout d:\whatever`

---

**Original Answer**:

The installer had a bug about this issue & as the team said, the bug fixed in `v15.1` (release date: 4/6/2017).

I could download `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb` workload with following command successfully. (*1.79GB*)

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeRecommended --includeOptional`

Comment: I got --add to download one workload, but if I try to download additional workloads or components using the same syntax (just like your example above), it fails to download anything. What's the trick?

Comment: @ScottHutchinson since I wrote this answer the way of download has a bit changed, now you can handle the `workload(s)` using custom `response.jdon`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automated-installation-with-response-file